# Convert int 14236 to hex 379C as char[37,9C] in C++

Tags: c++, hex, int, dhcp

**Background**

I am creating a simple BOOTP/DHCP server, and I am struggling with creating some of the packet bytes - in particular, the DHCP option 13, FileSize.

The spec states the option as having a total length of 64 bytes => 1 byte for ID (13), 1 byte for data length, and the remaining bytes as data OR 0.

**Problem**

I need to express the int value 14236 as my data, which equates to 379C in HEX, but this needs to be spread over 2 bytes of data. How do I take an int and get a char[] of the data?

Comment: Int to char ? itoa() http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdlib/itoa/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int size = 14236;
unsigned char bytes[2] = { (size >> 8) & 0xff, size & 0xff };

printf("%x%x", bytes[0], bytes[1]);
```

**Be careful:** You need to make sure the two bytes are placed in the array in network order, which if I 'm not mistaken is big endian.

Comment: First answer, and it works. Thanks guys! Now to polish up my rusty C++ skills.

Answer (score 4):

It likely needs to be in network byte order.  If so, then you can use `htons`.  If you want it in the second two bytes:

```
char buffer[4];
buffer[0] = 13;   // code
buffer[1] = 2;    // length
*(uint16_t*)(buffer + 2) = htons( 14236 );
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use this code:

```
int size;
assert(size < 0x10000);

unsigned char twoBytes[];
twoBytes[0] = size & 0xFF;
twoBytes[1] = size >> 8;
```

Answer (score 0):

So, you have the packet:

```
unsigned char optionBytes[64];
```

Then you set the ID and data lengths:

```
optionBytes[0] = 13;
optionBytes[1] = 2;
```

And finally, compute the upper and lower bytes of your value:

```
optionBytes[2] = 14236 / 256;
optionBytes[3] = 14236 % 256;
```

This assumes you want the data represented in "big-endian" format, with values on lower offsets being worth more.